# No longer able to edit text areas in an external editor with vimperator

Tags: firefox, vimperator

I'm running Vimperator 3.8 on Firefox 25.  I am no longer to able to use `C-i` to edit a text area in an external editor on sites that are trapping `C-i` for their own use.  This has become particularly noticable on StackExchange-esque sites (like this one!).

Previously, the `C-i` would get handled both by Vimperator and by the site (so, I would get `*emphasized text*` in the text area *and* the text area would open in an external editor).  Now, only the site is handling the keystroke.

I think this is a Firefox problem; I've tried installing [It's All
Text](https://addons.mozilla.org/EN-us/firefox/addon/its-all-text/)
and setting the hotkey to `C-i` but the behavior is the same
(fortunately, *It's all Text* makes it easy to set the hotkey so I'm
set it to `A-i` instead, which works fine).

Is there any way to either (a) map another key to open the text area in an external editor or (b) to get `C-i` working again?

Answer (score 0):

Stackexchange disables the WMD preview for smartphones, so you can, if you change your User-Agent to `iphone;` `ipad;` or `android n.n;

Source: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33116/really-annoying-wysiwyg-editor-interaction-with-vimperator